# How long does it take to process a flag?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578677/212940) 5 days ago

[image: Flag text]

It seems to me that this is a much longer than usual time to process a flag. What is going on?

This question is **not** about the validity or otherwise of the flag.

Comment: `"This should be a comment"` => should be flagged `"Not an answer"`. Don't use custom flags for that.

Comment: @Dukeling I specifically said that this is not about the validity of the flag. I will, as always, quite happily accept the moderators' decision on that. It is actually an answer, but it shouldn't be, hence the need for a mod's attention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current moderator queue (as of 5/15/14) has approximately 1.5k+ flags to be reviewed.  It takes us a little while to process them you must have patience young Padawan.

This flag in particular was flagged using "Other" so only moderators can handle it.  If it was a Low Quality or a Not An Answer, those get funneled into the Low Quality Review queue and can be handled by the community instead of a moderator.

Comment: Also, we tend to triage flags based on what we can, and need to, act  on immediately. Lower-priority flags or ones that might take a little more work to handle can sometimes take longer to process.