# Is it legit to flag this answer?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

In review I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13745604/3330969) (Visible to 10K user). The answer contains only links so I flag it as "Not an Answer" 2-3 days ago. In my flag history this flag is still pending.

Could this answer be considered as a link-only answer or not?

Screenshot of answer :

> [image]

Comment: On another note, please don't use code spans (`like this`) for emphasis.

Comment: I would say it is NAA because if you strip out the links, it basically says, "Progress Dialog" which the OP already knew about but wanted to know *how* to use it.

Comment: Relevant: [your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I've consistently flagged "link-only" answers, and rarely been denied. Edit: the answer's gone it seems.

Comment: Also relevant, if you are concerned about the time that passed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255084/how-long-does-it-take-to-process-a-flag

Comment: can't see the answer now.  Apparently it's been deleted since the question was posted.

Comment: @La-comadreja, I have added the screenshot.

Comment: With over 7K views on question, 10 upvotes, 3 downvotes on answer, some users have find that useful.

Comment: @Habib, agree ,even I found it very useful, but still the answer is Link only as per the link only answer's defination.

Comment: @Kedarnath, I am not sure/aware if a link only answer should be flagged as NAA, I can't seem to find any official policy about the issue, It appears that in the questions I have seen like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/181661) , the issue is debatable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, I went and deleted it. [We normally try to avoid deleting accepted answers unless in exceptional circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer); in this case:

- The fact that none of the text in the links provides any sort of useful information means that this answer fits the strictest definition of link-only. An answer is not an answer when, absent any of the links, all it does is regurgitate some keywords from the question in some specific order.
- But more importantly, the fact that the answer consists of not one, two, or three, but *seven* links, means that if someone were to attempt to expand and elaborate on the links, the answer would become unmaintainable, since they clearly all point to seven distinct standalone resources.

  That lends itself to another problem: the question is too broad. It's also not well-defined; all it asks is how to create a custom progress control, with an image that isn't exactly the most descriptive either.

Answer (score 4):

It is a non-suitable answer to a non-suitable question.  The question is essentially a "recommend a tutorial" type question, given the amount of visible work that was put into trying to solve the problem.  It was rightfully put on hold.  (If it were explicitly worded as such, I would probably redirect the User to Quora.)  The answer, needless to say, had a long list of tutorials without any commentary on them, and fit very neatly into the link-only answer category.

Wikipedia "External links" is a very nice place to compile a list of external tutorials.  In principle, the community of editors can oversee that the links do not go bad.

One of the reasons SO has this policy about links is that it is not designed for individual answers to be reviewed and content-changed by many people, as Wikipedia is.  If links go bad, a link-only answer becomes off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it definitely could because it **does** only contain links. I would flag that post too. If I was nicer, I would tell the user to add some text and program into the post, and rescue him from getting flagged. Still, I would rather flag him.