# Does Community ♦ edit deleted post?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-user

[Is it legit to flag this answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255116/996493)

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13745604/996493) in 2014 and it was deleted by a moderator on the same date.

Today, when I visited the answer link, I saw this:

[image: Screenshot of deleted post]

So, if the answer was deleted in 2014, why did Community ♦ modify the answer in 2017?

Comment: To update links to Stack Exchange sites to HTTPS

Comment: ok, but then why it didnt updated all the links from that post ? Check [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13745604/revisions)

Comment: Not all of those links point to sites in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: @Lucifer because it was SO that moved to HTTPS - not all other links could reliably be changed to that without potentially breaking things...

Comment: @Lucifer How do you notice this? I mean you fllagged this answer before four years ago... How did you find it was edited last year?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson, Please read my question again. Also I have higher reputation so that I can see deleted posts. That's why I come to know that answer was edited my Community.

Comment: @Lucifer _Today when I visit the answer_ you mean this? I saw it... But how did you find it? Ahh it from your profile (URL like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/8246224)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because **in theory** any such posts could be undeleted again in future.

Note that this was a one-off batch edit to replace `http://` Stack Exchange urls with their `https://` equivalent.