# "Other" flag review by tag experts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

I flagged an answer as "other" about 1 hour ago, and I was wondering how long it takes to process the flag. I came upon [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255084/how-long-does-it-take-to-process-a-flag) question which answered that the "other" flag processing is done by moderators (and that the queue is quite big). Is it an idea to let community members with a gold badge in the tag of the question to also review those flags?

In that way the workload for the moderators is also lowered, and I think the quality of the moderation can be assured.

Comment: Jeej first question on meta, first down vote. Why the downvote if I may ask?

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean that users disagree with your request.

Comment: @bluefeet oh ok, it is maybe an idea then to change the text when you hover over the downvote button to that on meta?

Comment: @bluefeet or is it cover by "not usefull"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Other" flag should be used for stuff that can't be handled by the community and need some sort of moderator intervention.  This could be for a variety of reasons.

We can't funnel "Other" flags for community review because it is a freeform and could contain any number of descriptions for the flag - some of this we wouldn't want the community to see.

As far as the size of the review queue, yes it is large.  Currently, we have 1.6k+ items to be reviewed, this is why before flagging for "Other" you want to be sure that the community cannot handle this on their own.