# How long does it take to respond to a flag?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

I have found the following dupe (from May 2014):

[How long does it take to process a flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255084/how-long-does-it-take-to-process-a-flag)

**Does the same answer apply, or has the situation gotten worse?**

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090557/add-big-text-file-14-62-gb-to-database) on July 15th with the following:

*"It looks like to more than one of us the OP is trying to create a rainbow table. More gut feeling than anything."*

(I know, having a gut feeling is no proof or indictment but I think most would agree with the gut feeling.)

Rainbow table flags are generally handled very swiftly ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017530/insert-data-from-text-file-and-to-sql-refresh-every-10-inserts)) but this one might not seem as obvious, so I haven't been concerned about the flag not getting a response quickly. But 15 days have passed and I am curious if the same answer above still applies, perhaps even more so given increased traffic since 2014?

Comment: I'll note that the other question you point out was handled quickly because there were multiple flags on that and their other posts due to them insulting other members. Stuff like that can elevate the level of attention on things. Flags pointing out questions that might or might not be used for shady purposes can take longer because they're tough judgment calls to make. We'll sometimes kick the can around until someone decides to deal with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can take a while.

> [image: 1294 posts flagged for moderator attention]

Can't imagine why.

Comment: _The current moderator queue (as of 5/15/14) has approximately 1.5k+ flags to be reviewed._ So, it's actually quicker now?

Comment: I totally understand @Oded, but I have had posts I flagged for mods over the past couple of months which were handled very quickly. Does that mean those were higher in the queue somehow?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the number ebbs and flows. Depends on how many moderators are actively handling flags and how many are being raised. Some flag types get handled faster, some slower.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You just need to wait till you win the lottery; that'd be the type of scenario (I get out of this).

Comment: IIRC (and I might not) a higher number of flags on a question increases its visibility in the queue.

Comment: @BSMP You recall correctly. The more flags the closer to the front of the line it goes.